# WAMP WordPress Google Calendar Events error

Tags: wordpress, plugins, calendar, wamp

I am developing a WordPress site on my local computer using WAMP.

I get the following error:

> "There are no HTTP transports available which can complete the
>   requested request. Please ensure your feed URL is correct."

I suspect this is a WAMP configuration problem. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You have a problem in your php.ini file.

Comment out the line `;extension=php_curl.dll` and restart WAMP.

Comment: I assume you mean *uncomment* the line you cite?